# New install of Debian 9.5 x64 will only boot with Install USB drive inserted

Tags: linux, boot, debian

I just installed Debian 9.5 x64 (CLI only) on a new machine. I used a USB Flash drive as the install medium.

It installed, I rebooted leaving the flash drive in, and it booted up fine. I took the flash drive out and rebooted it and it won't boot I get the following error

```
ata0.200: failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0_40)
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/sbd2 does not exist. Dropping shell!
```

If I put the flash drive in and reboot, it will boot up to the login prompt correctly. If I take it out again it does not boot etc.

When it boots up without the flash drive the GRUB menu appears so I assume that means I didn't somehow but the bootloader on the wrong drive.

Finally, I did a complete reinstall again and I got the same result.

Could this have anything to do with UEFI? The first time I installed it asked if I wanted to use UEFI or Bios I choose UEFI. The second time I installed Debian I do not think it asked me about this.

Comment: I had something similar on Ubuntu, where booting with the USB drive inserted changed the drive device name allocation, so that the hard drive became `sdb` instead of `sda`. You should try modifying the boot record during boot-up with the USB drive removed. Once booted without the USB drive, run `sudo update-grub` and this should correct the boot settings for future boots.

Comment: check the grub loader, possibly you have it installed to /dev/sdb which is the USB drive. Boot to Debian USB drive once more and reinstall grub to /dev/sda

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub

Comment: @AFH, So using your suggestion. I booted up with the USB drive inserted (since it wouldn't boot otherwise. The USB drive was sda and the main drive was sdb. So your susgestion was correct. I pulled the USB drive out, ran sudo update-grub then rebooted. It now boots. However I still get the first line of the error "ata0.200: failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0_40)" to flash before I get the login prompt. Makes me a assume that first line was not part of the booting problem. Do you know what it is about?

Comment: @ Mr. Raspberry: Grub was installed to /dev/sdb which was correct because for some reason that was what the main drive was mounted to during install. the problem was that once I pulled the USB out and rebooted the main drive changed to sda, so running update-grub fixed that issue.

Comment: If the error message appeared just before the log-in screen, then it has nothing to do with `grub`, but it may be another side-effect of the confusion over the main disc name. Does it appear if you connect the USB after boot is under way?

Comment: @AFH: If I insert the USB drive then no the error message does not appear.

Comment: The system log may have some more information: try `sudo dmesg -H | less` after the first log-in on rebooting, then look for the message string - there may be more information in the log than in the pop-up.